# In groovy, how do I return a zero padded range?

Tags: groovy, jenkins-groovy

I need to return a value between 001-999.
so naturally i can use ranges:

```
return 1..999
```

but I need to return something between 001 and 999, meaning to zero pad the single and double digit numbers. 
Is there an elegant way to do this in groovy ?

I can of course do this with a for loop, but there is probably a more elegant way to do this i couldn't find.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Easy solution would be:

```
(1..999).collect { String.format('%03d', it) }
```

Manipulate`%03d` to pad with whatever padding needed. For example:

```
`%04d` => 0001
`%05d` => 00001
...... so on and so forth
```

Answer (score 4):

This can be a solution:

```
(1..999).collect {
    it.toString().padLeft(3, '0')
}
```

Or you may want your padding to be adjustable to the range:

```
def range = 1..999
def digitsNum = range.to.toString().length()
def padded = range.collect {
    it.toString().padLeft(digitsNum, '0')
}
```